# Not able to start square space development server on windows

Tags: java, npm, squarespace

Am setting up square space local development server on widows using below commands
but getting JAVA exception

I have installed npm in windows
npm version is : **6.14.6**

Installed square-space local development server using command

**npm install -g @squarespace/server**

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

> @squarespace/server@1.7.0 preinstall C:\Users\bilalbaig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@squarespace\server
> npm run accept && node scripts/execif.js --exists=build npm run copyrunscript


> @squarespace/server@1.7.0 accept C:\Users\bilalbaig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@squarespace\server
> node scripts/accept.js LICENSE.txt

Using this software requires accepting the Squarespace Developer Terms of Use and Oracle Binary Code License Agreement. See LICENSE.txt.
To read the file, press Enter. :

Squarespace Developer Terms of Use and Oracle Binary Code License Agreement

Use of the Squarespace Development Server software (ΓÇ£Dev ServerΓÇ¥) is governed by the Developer Terms of Use, available at http://developers.squarespace.com/developer-terms-of-use/. Java SE Runtime Environment Software is bundled with the Dev Server. By using the Dev Server, you agree to the Oracle Binary Code License Agreement for the Java SE Platform Products and JavaFX, available at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html.

Do you accept the Squarespace Developer Terms of Use and Oracle Binary Code License Agreement?
Please type 'yes' and press Enter to accept. Type 'read' to read again. Type 'no' to reject. : yes
Executing: npm run copyrunscript

> @squarespace/server@1.7.0 copyrunscript C:\Users\bilalbaig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@squarespace\server
> node scripts/copyfile.js build/distributions/local-developer/bin/run.bat darwin:build/distributions/local-developer/bin/osx-local-developer win32:build/distributions/local-developer/bin/win-local-developer.bat linux:build/distributions/local-developer/bin/linux-local-developer build/distributions/local-developer/bin/local-developer

copying build/distributions/local-developer/bin/win-local-developer.bat to build/distributions/local-developer/bin/run.bat
C:\Users\bilalbaig\AppData\Roaming\npm\squarespace-server -> C:\Users\bilalbaig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@squarespace\server\build\distributions\local-developer\bin\run.bat

> @squarespace/server@1.7.0 postinstall C:\Users\bilalbaig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@squarespace\server
> node scripts/execif.js --exists=build npm run bundle && npm run cleanupscript

Executing: npm run bundle

> @squarespace/server@1.7.0 bundle C:\Users\bilalbaig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@squarespace\server
> node scripts/bundlejre.js --accept --clear -tz -j 8u131 -o build/distributions/runtimes/jre

Bundling compatible JRE (This may take a while)

> @squarespace/server@1.7.0 cleanupscript C:\Users\bilalbaig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@squarespace\server
> node scripts/execif.js --os=win32 --exists=build node scripts/vetolines.js build/distributions/local-developer/bin/run.bat #!

Executing: node scripts/vetolines.js build/distributions/local-developer/bin/run.bat #!
Removing 1 lines starting with '#!' in build/distributions/local-developer/bin/run.bat
+ @squarespace/server@1.7.0
updated 1 package in 185.088s
```

*It installed successfully*

after this I move to my template directory and run command

`squarespace-server https://conch-flugelhorn-hzkm.squarespace.com/ --auth`

but its giving me this error

```
$ squarespace-server https://conch-flugelhorn-hzkm.squarespace.com/ --auth
off

D:\folio3-projects\squarespace\template>echo off
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/bilalbaig/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@squarespace/server/build/distributions/local-developer/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/bilalbaig/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@squarespace/server/build/distributions/local-developer/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
23:33:36,707 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
23:33:36,707 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
23:33:36,708 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/C:/Users/bilalbaig/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@squarespace/server/build/distributions/local-developer/lib/local-developer.jar!/logback.xml]
23:33:36,709 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
23:33:36,710 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/C:/Users/bilalbaig/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@squarespace/server/build/distributions/local-developer/lib/local-developer.jar!/logback.xml]
23:33:36,710 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/C:/Users/bilalbaig/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@squarespace/server/build/distributions/local-developer/lib/src.jar!/logback.xml]
23:33:36,738 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@c038203 - URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/bilalbaig/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@squarespace/server/build/distributions/local-developer/lib/local-developer.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
23:33:36,827 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
23:33:36,842 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
23:33:36,854 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
23:33:36,899 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
23:33:36,962 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [__RequestLogger] to INFO
23:33:36,962 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.squarespace.developer.autoreload.ReloadFileWatcher] to INFO
23:33:36,962 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [io.dropwizard.server.ServerFactory] to INFO
23:33:36,962 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR
23:33:36,962 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
23:33:36,963 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
23:33:36,964 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@cc285f4 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.dropwizard.server.SimpleServerFactory.setRequestLogFactory(Lio/dropwizard/request/logging/RequestLogFactory;)V
        at com.squarespace.developer.DevelopmentServer.configureLogging(DevelopmentServer.java:117)
        at com.squarespace.developer.DevelopmentServer.run(DevelopmentServer.java:73)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:40)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:77)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:70)
        at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:80)
        at com.squarespace.developer.DevelopmentServer.main(DevelopmentServer.java:61)
```

I have tried multiple solutions but not able to fix it

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue. It seems like the latest update 1.7.0 from last week broke something so rolling back to a previous version fixed it for me.

`npm uninstall -g @squarepace/server`

`npm install -g @squarespace/server@1.6.2`

Comment: After a lot of googling, this solution worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Fast and easy bandaid. I hope they fix it in the next update.